# Payment terms data in international trade is needed

Tags: trade

There are payment terms in international trade when an import or export is made. Advance Payment, Letter of Credit, Acceptance, Cash Against Documents etc are the types of the payments. 
I can't find a global data or data for some countries regarding payment terms statistics.